# How the async Task return conditionally

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous

Hi am trying to return for an async method task conditionally. Below is the way I tried.

```
public string DoMessage(MyObj obj)
    {
        string returnStatus = "Processing...";
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"]);
        if (queue.CreateIfNotExists())            {
        }

        var msg = CloudQueueMessageExtensions.Serialize(obj);
        queue.AddMessage(msg);

        //Task processTask = RunMessageProces();
        var t = Task.Run(() => RunMessageProces());
        t.Wait();
        return  returnStatus;
    }

    private async Task<string> RunMessageProces()  
    {
        statusProcess = "Your message successfully inserted in process queue.";
        await Task.Run(() => {
            lock (_oQueue)
            {
                if (flagProcessing == true) //return when queue processing alredy started
                {
                    return statusProcess; //Error ..??? how to return 
                }
                flagProcessing = true; //else start processing the queue till there are messages.
            }
        });
        statusProcess = ProcessMyMessage();
        return statusProcess;
    }

    private string ProcessMyMessage() {...}
```

What I am missing? How to return string in between conditionally under async method that too lie inside await lock anonymous block(?). I do async in task as Do Message is flooded with lot of calls simultaneously due to exposed part of a service.

Comment: Hy, please, can you give a minimal running example, so we can try?

Comment: Here it goes..public string DoMessage() { var t = Task.Run(() => RunMessageProces());}
 private async Task<string> RunMessageProces()  //async Task<string>
        {            statusProcess = "MSG.";  await Task.Run(() => {   //FIRST ERROR HERE...
  lock (_oQueue)    { if (flagProcessing == true) { return statusProcess;  //SECOND ERROR HERE.                      
} flagProcessing = true; //else start processing the queue till there are messages.
} });  statusProcess = BigTimeConsumingProcess(); return statusProcess;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking how to access the returned value from the task.

```
  private async Task<string> RunMessageProces()
    {
        var statusProcess = "Your message successfully inserted in process queue.";
       var retValue =  await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_oQueue)
            {
                if (flagProcessing == true) //return when queue processing alredy started
                {
                    return "Error"; // or some such error indicator
                }
                flagProcessing = true; //else start processing the queue till there are messages.
            }
            return string.Empty; // return a string here too....
        });

        // if( retValue == "Error" ) { return "Error" } 
        statusProcess = ProcessMyMessage();
        return statusProcess;
    }
```

Comment: Hi shr, Note that the return inside lock is giving errors. First is for await Task.Run statement that "not all code path return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' " (which I not required to return always but conditionally) and  second error in return "Error" statement that "Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Threading.Tasks.Task."

Comment: @AKS, It is working for me. To fix the first error, you need a return string either after the lock block or after the if block. I have a return string.Empty in my code.  Paste the updated code, so that I can have a look.

Comment: Thanks shr, I got it, wrongly assumed that return "Error"; inside lock is returning from the function RunMessageProces but it was actually a return  to Task.Run only. Your extra code like var retValue = and the last commented check open the doors of knowledge. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AKS, on an additional note, you don't need an additional task to call RunMessageProces. You can var t = await RunMessageProcess()

Comment: Thanks for var t = await RunMessageProcess(); but to make this happen there need to change the method where this line exists which is a WCF exposed method/contract to append async in front of it to allow await. that will probably break the existing caller of the service.